# pagination doesn't work when I click on button javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, pagination

My pagination returns data from the database but when I click for example the second page button it say:

`The requested URL /MFPTMA/poserquestion-Copie.php was not found on this server.`

```
<?php  
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(idra) FROM reponsea";  
    $rs_result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs_result);  
    $total_records = $row[0];  
    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);  
    $pagLink = "<nav><ul class='pagination'>";  
    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  
         $pagLink .= "<li>
                        <a href='poserquestion-Copie.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."
                        </a>
                      </li>";  
    }  

    echo $pagLink . "</ul></nav>";  
?>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.pagination').pagination({
            items: <?php echo $total_records;?>,
            itemsOnPage: <?php echo $limit;?>,
            cssStyle: 'light-theme',
            currentPage : <?php echo $page;?>,
            hrefTextPrefix : 'poserquestion-Copie.php?page='
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, the file doesn't exists. Add the file in the correct location and it will work

Comment: thank for the answer but sorry I didn't understad your point. the file is the same file! I am not opening a new one

Comment: And the filename you're outputting (poserquestion-Copie.php) is the exact name (case-sensitive wise)?

Comment: thanks a lot it was there the problem. now it works. the file name is poserquestion - Copie.php not poserquestion-Copie.php

Comment: BTW, you can do `echo basename( $_SERVER[ "PHP_SELF" ] );` and it will output the filename for you, in case you'll decide to change the name of the file, but forget to update its name in the code

Comment: done :) thanks again I'm beginner in php and English also

Comment: @AlonEitan sorry for distrub but I have another problem if you have any idea. the buttons in pagiation present the texts: prev 1 2 3 next. now I need to change it to: premier 1 2 3 suivant. I've trid to change them from jquery.simplepagination.js but they didn't change

Comment: Add `prevText: "premier", nextText: "suivant"` to the `pagination({ ... })` part

Answer (score 1):

If you put the URL like this:

```
<a href='poserquestion-Copie.php?page=".$i."'>
```

This will be a relative URL. This URL is relative to the current path. What this means is that it will resolve to different paths depending on where you are in the site.

The best practice here is you should put a absolute URL here. Absolute URL can be:

```
<a href='/poserquestion-Copie.php?page=".$i."'>
```

Or:

```
<a href='/<custom path>/poserquestion-Copie.php?page=".$i."'>
```

Or even including domain of your site:

```
<a href='<domain>/<custom path>/poserquestion-Copie.php?page=".$i."'>
```

Comment: the problem was with the spelling of the file name. thanks for your answer